# SWIG error on template wrapping

Tags: python, c++, templates, swig

I am trying to wrap a piece of code in python using SWIG. The following is the interface file:

```
/* dnn_face_embedding_extractor.ii */
%module dnn_face_embedding_extractor
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
extern template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class      block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>;
extern template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>;
extern template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> ;
extern std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> am_main(char* image_name);
%}

%template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
%template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
%template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> ;
extern std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> am_main(char* image_name);
```

And I encounter the following error:
dnn_face_embedding_extractor.ii:11: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
Can anyone help me?

P.S. I want to wrap the code below, which is error free and I can compile it. It's also noteworthy that the code is highly inspired from an example in Dlib.

```
#include <dlib/dnn.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/clustering.h>
#include <dlib/string.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
using residual = add_prev1<block<N,BN,1,tag1<SUBNET>>>;

template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
using residual_down = add_prev2<avg_pool<2,2,2,2,skip1<tag2<block<N,BN,2,tag1<SUBNET>>>>>>;

template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> 
using block  = BN<con<N,3,3,1,1,relu<BN<con<N,3,3,stride,stride,SUBNET>>>>>;

template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares      = relu<residual<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;
template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares_down = relu<residual_down<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;

template <typename SUBNET> using alevel0 = ares_down<256,SUBNET>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel1 = ares<256,ares<256,ares_down<256,SUBNET>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel2 = ares<128,ares<128,ares_down<128,SUBNET>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel3 = ares<64,ares<64,ares<64,ares_down<64,SUBNET>>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel4 = ares<32,ares<32,ares<32,SUBNET>>>;

using anet_type = loss_metric<fc_no_bias<128,avg_pool_everything<
                        alevel0<
                        alevel1<
                        alevel2<
                        alevel3<
                        alevel4<
                        max_pool<3,3,2,2,relu<affine<con<32,7,7,2,2,
                        input_rgb_image_sized<150>
                        >>>>>>>>>>>>;

std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> am_main(char* image_name) try{
    // The first thing we are going to do is load all our models.  First, since we need to
    // find faces in the image we will need a face detector:
frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    // We will also use a face landmarking model to align faces to a standard pose:  (see face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp for an introduction)
    shape_predictor sp;
    deserialize("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat") >> sp;
    // And finally we load the DNN responsible for face recognition.
    anet_type net;
    deserialize("dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat") >> net;

    matrix<rgb_pixel> img;
    load_image(img, image_name);

    // Run the face detector on the image of our action heroes, and for each face extract a
    // copy that has been normalized to 150x150 pixels in size and appropriately rotated
    // and centered.
    std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;
    for (auto face : detector(img))
    {
        auto shape = sp(img, face);
        matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
        extract_image_chip(img, get_face_chip_details(shape,150,0.25), face_chip);
        faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
    }

    if (faces.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "No faces found in image!" << endl;
        std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> face_descriptors;
        return face_descriptors;
    }

    // This call asks the DNN to convert each face image in faces into a 128D vector.
    // In this 128D vector space, images from the same person will be close to each other
    // but vectors from different people will be far apart.  So we can use these vectors to
    // identify if a pair of images are from the same person or from different people.  
    std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> face_descriptors = net(faces);
    return face_descriptors;
    // return 0;
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your C++ isn't even legal, e.g. `extern template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> ;` is missing something like a variable declaration or a function declaration or a class definition/declaration to even be legal. I can't actually figure out from what you've shown here what your C++ interface does which is a precursor to answering how to make it work with SWIG. Can you make a minimal, complete example that show (at least with minimal valid C++) how the templates are expected to work?

Comment: I just added the C++ code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Swig documentation at http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn30, section 6.18 Templates. You need to instantiate your template in your interface file, the parser expects that instantiation at line 11. Try something like:

```
%template (MyStdVector) std::vector<matrix<float,0,1> >;
```

and similar for the other templates.